# Lenovo A600 can't keep service running after app killed

Tags: android, android-studio

As the title, I just built an app using Unbound Service, but it didn't work fine on Lenovo A6000, when I killed app, the service which I started before was closed also. 
But services in Facebook, Messenger app worked on this device correctly.
So, how can I do?

Comment: Can you please post some menifest code so anyone can get help to help you.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel don't give wrong direction. This issue happen even we mention START_STICKY. This is device specific issue. That's the reason he mention the device name.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Nam Nguyen & ADM here is created service which work in background in my lenovo device after kill application,

Here you need to create to service, one is for the background task and one is alarm service for continuously check your service after some time,

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by DhavalSolanki on 30/3/17.
 */

public class ConnectionService extends Service {
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        context = getApplicationContext();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUnbind");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}





import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by DhavalSolanki on 30/3/17.
 */
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        boolean isServiceRunning = false;
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (ConnectionService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                isServiceRunning = true;
                break;
            }
        }
//        Logger.print("AlarmService", "Service is running " + isServiceRunning);
        if (!isServiceRunning) {
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConnectionService.class));
        } 
    }

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     */
    public AlarmService() {
        super("Alarm");
    }
}
```

Write following code where you start you service

```
 private void checkAndStartService() {
        final ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            boolean isServiceRunning = false;
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                    if (ConnectionService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                        isServiceRunning = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return isServiceRunning;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
                Log.i("onPostExecute", "Service running = " + aBoolean);
                if (!aBoolean) {

                    startService(new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, ConnectionService.class));
                    Intent i = new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, AlarmService.class);
                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(ActivitySplash.this, 0, i, 0);
                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ActivitySplash.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    am.cancel(pi); // cancel any existing alarms
                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pi);
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

And Finally register Both service in Manifest file

```
       <service android:name=".services.ConnectionService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.AlarmService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```